# I'm trying to convert a HTML template to PDF with pdfkit but the data from the template not loaded in the pdf

Tags: html, django, pdfkit

```
views.py

def resume(request,id):
    user_profile=Profile.objects.get(pk=id) 
    template= loader.get_template("Resume/profile.html")
    html= template.render({'user_profile':user_profile})
    options={
        'page-size':'Letter',
        'encoding' : 'UTF-8',
        
    }

    pdf= pdfkit.from_string(html,False,options)
    response= HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition']= 'attachment' 
    return response




profile.html

{% extends "Resume/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
  
  <h2>{{ user_profile.full_name }}</h2>
  <h2>{{ user_profile.job_title }}</h2>
  <hr>
  <h2>{{ user_profile.email }}</h2>
  <h2>{{ user_profile.phone }}</h2>
  <h2>{{ user_profile.home_adress }}</h2>
  
  <hr>

  <p>Summary</p>
  <p> {{ user_profile.work_experience }}</p>
  <p> {{ user_profile.skills }}</p>
  <hr>
  
  <p>Education</p>
  <ul>
      <li>
          {{user_profile.diplomes}}
      </li>
  </ul>
  <hr>

{% endblock %}
```

![this is th pdf i get ][1]

[1]:( https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXlt3.png)

I'm trying to convert a HTML template to PDF with pdfkit but the data from the template not loaded in the pdf
can anyone help me with this, i don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your resume function:
instead of:

```
template= loader.get_template("Resume/profile.html")
html= template.render({'user_profile':user_profile}
```

use this:

```
html = loader.render_to_string('Resume/profile.html', {'user_profile':user_profile})
```

your code will look like this:

```py
from django.template import loader
def resume(request,id):
    user_profile=Profile.objects.get(pk=id)
    html = loader.render_to_string('Resume/profile.html', {'user_profile':user_profile})
    options={
        'page-size':'Letter',
        'encoding' : 'UTF-8',
    }
    
    pdf= pdfkit.from_string(html, pdf_url)
    response= HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition']= 'attachment'
    return response
```